# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sin^n1+\cos^n1)^n$?

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the following limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sin^n1+\cos^n1)^n \, .$$
As far as I understand, this limit is not an indeterminate form.

I tried rearranging the terms a bit but that  doesn't help:
$$
[\sin^n1(1+\cot^n1)]^n$$
$$[\sin^n1]^n\cdot[(1+\cot^n1)]^n
$$

I did have this idea of considering $\cot^n1$ as negligible since the value of $\cot 1$ is less than $1$ and since it's raised to power infinity it would approach zero
but I'm not sure what to do with the $[\sin^n1]^n$

Note:The answer is $\sin1$.

Comment: Did you intend to intend have an equals sign on the first line?

Comment: $\sin^n 1 +\cos^n 1 \to 0 + 0 =0$. The limit is of the form $0^{\infty}$ and of course equals zero.

Comment: If you were told the answer is $\sin1$, then you have a typo. But by now your question has been answered as is, so please don't change it.

Comment: @Tavish that reasoning is flawed, since in the same way you could argue that since $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})  = 1$, we must have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1$ as well, which is false...

Comment: @noam.szyfer: that's not a $0^\infty$. It doesn't work the same.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, so that's actually a thing with $"0^\infty"$? If so, excuse my comment, I have never heard of that and it seems to me that one must be careful with these kinds of calculations...

Comment: $1^\infty$ is undefined but $0^\infty$ goes to 0 just fine. Small things to big exponents just become smaller.

Comment: @noam.szyfer: What Martin means that if you have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)\to0$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a$, then it *must* be the case that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanations Martin, Eric & Joe. Sorry for my comment then. I'll leave it here, just in case someone else struggles at the same point as I just did!

Comment: @noam.szyfer: I'm glad I could help. Incidentally, this is why expressions like "$0^0$" are called "indeterminate forms"—if you have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)\to0$ and $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to a$, then without more information, it is impossible to evaluate $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)^{g(x)}$. However, in this case "$0^0$" is just a shorthand for a limit—it does not refer to raising $0$ to itself. The *number* $0^0$ is very often defined as $1$, though not always.

Comment: @noam.szyfer: if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$, then for $x$ close enough to $x_0$ you have $|f(x)|<1/2$. If you also have that $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=\infty$, then for $x$ close enough to $x_0$ you get that $g(x)>M$ for a given $M$. Combining the two things, $|f(x)^{g(x)}|<1/2^M$ for $x$ close enough to $x_0$. That's a proof that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)^{g(x)}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

I note $x_n=\sin(1)^n+\cos(1)^n$. Since $0<\sin(1)<1$ and $0<\cos(1)<1$, we have $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} x_n=0.$
So, for sufficiently large $n, x_n<0.5$. For these sufficiently large $n$, we have $0<x_n^n<0.5^n$. So $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} x_n^n=0.$

Comment: Even easier $x_n^n<x_n$

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned in the question, that you intend to **find** the limit and not exactly prove it rigorously.

So, one easy way to go about this is to sketch the graphs of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ and see what happens. You observe, that $\sin x$ starts takes the value $0$ at $x=0$ and $y=1$ at $x=\pi/2$ and $\cos(x)$ takes the value $1$ at $x=0$ and $y=0$ at $x=\pi/2$.

Now, $\pi/2\approx1.57$. So, at $x=1$, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ both are $<1$ (Why?). Clearly,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^n=0$$ when $a<0$. So, the limit given in your question $\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$